# Different native character set across systems - ICHAR

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm using ICHAR in some code which will be used across different systems. The sample code is:

```
write(20,rec=iwrite) ichar(some_string(index))
```

where I'm trying to write some text to a binary file.

Looking at the the description on the GCC GNU website, it says:

> ICHAR(C) returns the code for the character in the first character
> position of C in the system’s native character set. The correspondence
> between characters and their codes is not necessarily the same across
> different GNU Fortran implementations.

It works fine on the few systems I've tried, e.g. a few computers with different versions of GCC, and a couple of clusters. But it seems that I won't even know it is writing the wrong data until I look at it, which is worrying.

1. Is there more detail about what is meant by different GNU Fortran implementations?
2. Is this compiler specific?
3. Is there a more robust way to write characters to a binary file, i.e. that will always write the same code to the file and always refers to the same character?

Comment: You might look into achar and iachar which use the ASCII collating sequence. I don't want to say more as I've never worked anywhere where the character set is likely to be different from something that looks like ASCII.